# Using only the SMS-function on Huawei E3372 dongle (still in need of wi-fi)

Tags: python, sms, huawei-mobile-services, dongle

I'm trying to write a python script where I automatically can send text messages. I am achieving this by using a Huawei E3372 dongle which is doing its work so far.

The problem:

Whenever I plug in the dongle, my whole network changes to this dongle. This is a problem because I'm pulling the text message data from an excel sheet that gets downloaded a few minutes before sending the texts out.

The solution I'm hoping for:

Is there any way I can use a wi-fi network and the dongle simultaneously? I know this might be a stretch but the only workaround I'm seeing is to turn off the actual network, which is giving me another problem:

When i use

```
    C:\Users\x>wmic nic get name, index
Index  Name
0      Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
1      Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
2      Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM
3      Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
4      Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
5      WAN Miniport (SSTP)
6      WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
7      WAN Miniport (L2TP)
8      WAN Miniport (PPTP)
9      WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
10     WAN Miniport (IP)
11     WAN Miniport (IPv6)
12     WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)
13     Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
14     Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device
```

14 should be the device, then I use:

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=14 call enable
```

I get the message:

```
    C:\Users\xxx>wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=14 call enable
Executing (\\NB-ACCOUNTMGR\root\cimv2:Win32_NetworkAdapter.DeviceID="14")->enable()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ReturnValue = 0;
};
```

Does anyone know why this happens? Even better, is there a fix so I dont have to use all this?

Comment: I will try to disable the usb device instead; later more

Comment: You need to provide details of your system, including network configurations. Are you trying to access your LAN, linked via Wi-Fi? Normally there's no problem accessing both LTE and Wi-Fi networks.